# python: shuffle characters in string to get all possible string combinations

Tags: python, string, combinations

just looking for a script in Python which receives some string and returns all possible strings made up of all the possible combinations of the chars in the original string...

I've found scripts to shuffle randomly the chars in a string, but they only return one randome combination, and what I'm looking for is all the possible combinations...

Say, for example:

```
script.py "abc"
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(list(itertools.permutations("spam")))
[('s', 'p', 'a', 'm'),
 ('s', 'p', 'm', 'a'),
 ('s', 'a', 'p', 'm'),
 ('s', 'a', 'm', 'p'),
 ('s', 'm', 'p', 'a'),
 ('s', 'm', 'a', 'p'),
 ('p', 's', 'a', 'm'),
 ('p', 's', 'm', 'a'),
 ('p', 'a', 's', 'm'),
 ('p', 'a', 'm', 's'),
 ('p', 'm', 's', 'a'),
 ('p', 'm', 'a', 's'),
 ('a', 's', 'p', 'm'),
 ('a', 's', 'm', 'p'),
 ('a', 'p', 's', 'm'),
 ('a', 'p', 'm', 's'),
 ('a', 'm', 's', 'p'),
 ('a', 'm', 'p', 's'),
 ('m', 's', 'p', 'a'),
 ('m', 's', 'a', 'p'),
 ('m', 'p', 's', 'a'),
 ('m', 'p', 'a', 's'),
 ('m', 'a', 's', 'p'),
 ('m', 'a', 'p', 's')]
```

(The `pprint` is just there to make the output look neater.) Or, if you prefer,

```
>>> list(map("".join, itertools.permutations("spam")))
['spam', 'spma', 'sapm', 'samp', 'smpa', 'smap', 'psam', 'psma', 'pasm', 'pams', 'pmsa', 'pmas', 'aspm', 'asmp', 'apsm', 'apms', 'amsp', 'amps', 'mspa', 'msap', 'mpsa', 'mpas', 'masp', 'maps']
```

Answer (score 5):

[`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) does that.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for s in itertools.permutations('banana'):
...     print ''.join(s)
... 
banana
banaan
bannaa
bannaa
# many, many more...
```